# Converting a simple query into a tricky named scope in RoR

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

I have a simple scoping question.  I would like to do this as a scope:

```
if article.responses.blank?
      return false
elsif article.responses.last.passed.eql?(false)
      return true
else
   return false
end
```

So on the article model I would have something like this:

```
scope :failed_response, {
    :joins=>[:responses],
    :conditions=>["responses.passed = ?", false]
  }
```

The problem is, I only want instances where the *most recent*  response failed.  I'm sure these is a way to do this with either fancy sorting or some kind of nested query, but I'm stuck.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of at the moment is a subquery inside the scope:

```
named_scope :failed_response, {
  :conditions => ["(SELECT passed FROM responses WHERE 
     responses.article_id = articles.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) = ?", false]
}
```

I guess there is some kind of Rails way that is a bit nicer or a way without a subquery, but I can't think of it at the moment. Hope this helps though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to make it clear than clever.  Have a instance method to return the last_reponse for that individual article and then have another instance method to return boolean of whether that's true or false.  It may not be as fast as a name scope with single line of SQL.  But I still do it the clear way for better maintainability/understanding.