# Named Scope to only search first results of joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

I'm having trouble with a named scope, SQL not my strong suit.

I would like to return ALL Machines which had it's LAST test fail.

My Machines model:

```
  has_many :lodged_tests, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :last_test, :class_name => 'LodgedTest', :order => 'created_at DESC'

  named_scope :last_test_failed, :joins => :last_test, :conditions => [ "lodged_tests.is_passed = ?", false]
```

The named_scope does work except it returns Machines which have ANY failed tests.
I need it to return machines which only the most recent(LAST) test failed.

Below is link to a quick diagram of what i'm trying to do.

[Named Scope Diagram](http://bits-n-pieces.s3.amazonaws.com/named-scope-SO.png)

any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to achieve the desired result using SQL, not very rails like but it gets the job done.

needed to include the limit of 1 in a subselect in the conditions.

```
named_scope :last_test_failed, :conditions => ["(SELECT is_passed FROM lodged_tests WHERE lodged_tests.machine_id = machines.id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1) = ?", false]
```

If anyone knows how to do this query using rails scope functions, I would be very interested to see an example.

This related S.O. question put me on the right path: [tricky named scope in RoR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629077/converting-a-simple-query-into-a-tricky-named-scope-in-ror/4629552#4629552)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a limit of 1?

```
named_scope :last_test_failed, :joins => :last_test, :conditions => [ "lodged_tests.is_passed = ?", false], :order => "created_at desc", :limit => 1
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I just gave suggestion a try and it seems to return the one most recent failed test in the whole account. I need it to return multiple results.

Comment: Ah, you said you wanted the LAST failed test. Remove the limit, and leave the order by.

Comment: I have attached a diagram to my question to help explain abit more what i'm trying to do.