# Ruby on Rails: Get all entities that have zero occurences on a particular association and condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, conditional-statements, named-scope

I am using Rails 2.3.8

I have two models that represent bikes and rentals on bikes respectively. One bike can have many rentals but at most one "acive" rental. I distinguish the active rentals with a status field in bike_rentals table with value `BIKE_RENTAL_OUT` (with other two possible values: `BIKE_RENTAL_RETURNED` and `BIKE_RENTAL_INCIDENT`)

To create a new rental I want to present to the user a listing of all bikes that are not currently rented, that is all the bikes that have no "active" rental (zero occurrences on an association with a particular condition).

I came up with a solution using a named scope as shown below:

```
class Bike < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bike_rentals
    named_scope :not_rented,
                :conditions => "bikes.id NOT IN " + 
                     "(SELECT bike_id FROM bike_rentals " + 
                     "WHERE bike_rentals.status = 'BIKE_RENTAL_OUT')"

end

class BikeRental < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bike
end
```

and in the controller I get that list as:

```
@bikes = Bike.not_rented.find(:all, :order => 'chasis_number')
```

The code above works, but I got the feeling that it must be a better solution or a more "The rails way" solution for this (presumable common) problem.

I know that I could use a counter cache for the number of "active" rentals a bike has but it seems a too complex solution for the task of just selecting all non "active" rentals which at most will return 1 per bike.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, You want to return all bikes which don't have a 'BIKE_RENTAL_OUT' status in the bikes has_may associated table bike_rentals. This should be able to be scoped like this:

```
named_scope :not_rented, :joins => :bike_rentals, :conditions => [ "bike_rentals.status != ?", BIKE_RENTAL_OUT]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately this is not enough because a bike can be in that join with BIKE_RENTAL_OUT and with BIKE_RENTAL_RETURNED at the same time, so it would still appear in the list returned by your named_scope. I need the bikes that do not have a row with BIKE_RENTAL_OUT regardless any other entries the same bike has in the join.

Comment: I'm not 100% percent sure what your saying, but if you mean that you only want to assess the status of the most recent rental for each bike then you will have to use a sub-select in your scope. here is a link to a question which shows this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858646/named-scope-to-only-search-first-results-of-joined-table